# Function printing correct Output and None

Tags: python

I have defined this function that takes a word and a string of required letters and that returns True if the word uses all the required letters at least once. When I run this, it gives me the correct output but I do not understand why it also outputs 'None'.

Here is my code:

```
 def uses_all(word, allused):
    boolean = False
    for e in allused:
        if e in word:
            boolean = True
        else:
            boolean = False
            break 
    print boolean 

print uses_all('facebook', 'd')
```

Output:

```
False
None
```

Comments on where I have gone wrong will be appreciated.

Comment: `boolean` is a bad name for a variable -- it tells us the type of the variable, which we already know, since it's either `True` or `False`, but you're not telling us what it *means*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program prints `boolean`, which is False, so you know where that comes from.

If a function doesn't return anything explicitly, it automatically returns None, and when you use

```
print uses_all('facebook', 'd')
```

you're asking it to print what `uses_all` returns, which is None.  Hence:

```
False
None
```

BTW, I think your function could be more concisely written as

```
def uses_all(word, allused):
    return all(e in word for e in allused)
```

Could make it more efficient, but that should be good enough for government work.  The [all](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) function is really handy (see also `any`).

Answer (score 5):

Because `uses_all()` doesn't have a return statement.  If you return a value from the function, it will be printed instead of None, unless of course you `return None` :)

Answer (score 0):

You print the result of the function, but the function doesn't `return` anything (--> None)

If you want the result to be `False False`, add `return boolean` in the function.

Alternatively, if a single `False` is enough, you could change `print uses_all('facebook', 'd')` to just `uses_all('facebook', 'd')`