# Why am I getting a None value, and why is the number still being printed in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function printing correct Output and None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466233/function-printing-correct-output-and-none)

Trying to print mutual users in a pretend twitter feed program. Homework. The numbers are users (ex `1111` is a user). The following set in the dictionary is a set of the key's friends.

I'd like this output:

```
Most friends in common
1111:   222 33333 5454
222:    1111 33333 5454
33333:  1111 222
5454:   1111 222
```

But instead have this output:

```
Most friends in common
1111 :  222 33333 5454  1111 None
222 :   1111 33333 5454  222 None
33333 :  1111 222  33333 None
5454 :   1111 222  5454 None
```

Here is my program:

```
all_users = {'1111': set(['5454', '222']), '33333': set(['5454']), '5454': set(['1111', '33333', '222']), '222': set(['1111', '5454'])}



def findmutual(id, all_users):
    users = []
    for key in all_users:
        mutual = all_users[id].intersection(all_users[key])
        rank = len(mutual)
        templist = [rank, key.strip()]
        users.append(templist)
    users = sorted(users)

    print users

    for item in users:
        if  id == item[1]:
            print "" ,
        if item[0] == 0:
            print "",
        else:
            print item[1],


users = []
for key in all_users:
    users.append(key)
users = sorted(users)
print "Most friends in common"
for item in users:
    print item, ":\t", findmutual(item, all_users)
```

Please help me to understand this issue!

Comment: Printing something in a function is different to *returning* a value. Because you don't have any `return` statements in `findmutual`, it returns `None`.

Comment: @Marius, sorry, I'll rephrase- if the twitter user name, or id, is equal to the mutual friend it is testing against, I do not want it to print that user ID (because it's not a mutual friend, it's itself)

Comment: It still prints the id because you have a print statement. It prints the id, then it returns None, which gets printed by the calling function.

Comment: As a general rule, functions take inputs and return outputs. Don't put side effects like print statements in functions. Have the caller (the user interface) print the result it gets.

Comment: @pearbear: It's a different language (PHP instead of Python), but I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9388327/128397) does a good job of explaining what is going on here.

Comment: Also, this has been asked lots of times before.  In a quick search I turned up [Function printing correct output and None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466233/function-printing-correct-output-and-none) which is a pretty exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in users:
    print item, ":\t", findmutual(item, all_users) # << That's why it shows None
```

What is happening here?

1. item = users[n]
2. print:

   1. item
   2. enter the function
   3. the function prints some more
   4. function ends and (automatically) returns None
   5. print the return value (which is None) of the function!

You probably want to change step 3-4!
instead of all print statements smth like:

```
result=''
...
result += '' #whatever
...
return result
```

**UPDATE:**

If i get you right, you are trying to establish a rank depending on who's the most popular?

In that case you might look int othat solution:

```
all_users = {'1111': set(['5454', '222']),
             '33333': set(['5454']),
             '5454': set(['1111', '33333', '222']),
             '222': set(['1111', '5454'])}

from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def findmutual(user_relation_map):    
    user_list = set(sorted(user_relation_map.keys()))
    user_ranking = defaultdict(int)
    for user in user_list:
        for friend in user_relation_map[user]:
            user_ranking[friend] += 1
    return user_ranking

c=Counter(findmutual(all_users))
print("Ranking : {0}".format(c.most_common()))

>>> Ranking : [('5454', 3), ('1111', 2), ('222', 2), ('33333', 1)]
```

Comment: I fixed the none- but I actually do want it to print. I'm trying to figure out now why the id reprints again as it goes through findmutual

Comment: i must confess i don't understand your code. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I've fixed it. My apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Dont hesitate to ask and/or clarify your intention! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`findmutual` doesn't return anything, which in Python is equivalent to returning `None`. So "None" is appearing in the output because you're telling it to print the return value of `findmutual(item, all_users)`, which is always `None`.

The numbers are still being printed because `findmutual` *itself* prints them. This is very rarely what you want, because it denies you the flexibility of calling `findmutual` to find the user ids and do anything else with them; every time you call it it will print them (even if you didn't want it to), and you don't get access to the numbers in Python to further manipulate.

Comment: I fixed the none- but I actually do want it to print. I'm trying to figure out now why the id reprints again as it goes through `findmutual`

Comment: @pearbear In `findmutual` you print things. You also print the return value of `findmutual`. If you don't want one of these things to print, don't print it.